# SQL71501: Trigger: [dbo].[TriggerName] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[TableName]

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2013, clr, sqlclr

I have a SQL Project with some functions and triggers.

In Visual Studio 2010, I could just specify the database connectionstring, and deploy. This worked great.

But now after migrating to Visual Studio 2013, I get a lot errors like this in a generated sql file when I try to build the project:

```
SQL71501: Trigger: [dbo].[TriggerName] has an unresolved reference 
to object [dbo].[TableName]
```

How should this be fixed?

Comment: Does your schema project have a script for [dbo].[TableName]? VS2013 is now validating the entire schema right there in the project.

Comment: @Erik Dekker, can you please explain me how you deployed your SQL CLR project  using visual studio 2010 and which SQL Server you are using. Actually I am trying to do the same but getting error. Here is my stackoverflow [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009477/system-invalidoperationexception-cannot-perform-cas-asserts-in-security-transpa) for more information.

Comment: Also please reply as answer to your own question here if you have resolved the it.

Comment: Hi, we still work in VS2010, and we use SQL Server 2008 R2. But your problem is totally different as ours. We only have a problem in VS 2012 and above because the behaviour is changed there and we need a complete schema to validate against now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove database reference before dbo in `CREATE TRIGGER` sql, then validation will succeed because visual studio will properly reference table in local project.

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar problem with 'SQL71501: unresolved reference to object'. It turns outs .sql file were not being added to the project in the manner expected by visual studio. The fix, for the case experienced, is to 'exclude' the .sql file from the project, and then re-'add' to the file to database project as an 'existing item'. That caused the references to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the database in Visual Studio for the trigger table. 
Go to Project>Import>Database.... Note if the [Database...] option is disabled in menu please try to close the solution and reopen it. 
Now before compiling the project please import the database which contains the table related to your trigger. It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working on SQL CLR trigger(s)

The CLR project had a reference to a "main" database project which contained all the tables I was attaching said trigger(s) to.

I had previously added a table to the "main" database project, but not re-built it.

I don't usually build it, since I'm just using it as a source-controlled place to store my schema.

So to fix the error, I needed to build the referenced Database project.

I suspect Visual Studio caches a representation of the last build of each database project to use for resolving object references.